# Week and day entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning `C#` and `MVC` with `ASP.NET`. I am making an application that takes daily data and splits it up into weeks.

My question is: How should I go about making the entities? I want it so that you have a `WeekNo` and a `DayNo` and you use them to display, edit and create data and tables. So for example, `WeekNo = 1` and `DayNo = 1` would be Monday in week 1. `WeekNo = 1` and `DayNo = 2` would be Tuesday and so on.

I'm new to this and not very good at information management. Do I need foreign keys?

I was thinking:

```
public class Day
{
    public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    public int DayID { get; set; }
    public int DayNo { get; set; }
    public string DayofWeek { get; set; }

    //then other declarations, not important

    [ForeignKey("DayNo")]
}

public class Week
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    public int DayofWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Does the foreign key go in Day or Week or do I even need it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `entities`? Object in the code? Elements in the Views? Tables in the Database?

Comment: Also, do you want an instance for each day or each week?

Comment: Ok, I posted my answer for if you mean Objects in the code, for both weekly and daily. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

On the **assumption that you meant `Object`s** when saying `entities`.

Here is how you can structure an `Object` for use **per day**:

```
public class myDailyObject
{
    public myDailyObject()
    { }

    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    public int DayNo { get; set; }
    public string DayofWeek { get; set; }

    //Other variables can go here.
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can use the following structure for use **per week**:

```
public class myWeeklyObject
{
    public myWeeklyObject()
    {
        DataByDay = new Dictionary<int, myDataObject>();
    }

    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, myDataObject> DataByDay { get; set; }
}

public class myDataObject
{
    //Other variables can go here.
}
```

In here, you can use the `Dictionary<int, myDataObject>` called `DataByDay` to contain an instance of the `myDataObject` `Object` for each day of the week.

---

**Example of usage**:

The Weekly object:

```
//Declare the weekly object:
myWeeklyObject thisWeek = new myWeeklyObject();
//Populate variables of thisWeek here:
thisWeek.ObjectID = thisWeek.WeekNo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
//The line above gets the current weekNo for the year.
```

You could also fetch this object from somewhere if one already exists for this week.

So now, the daily object:

```
//Get the day of the week as an int:
int dayOfWeek = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 1; //DayOfWeek is 0 based
//Daclare object for a specific day:
myDataObject newObject = new myDataObject();
//Populate variables of newObject here.
//Then add it with the int dayOfWeek as the Key to the DataByDay Dictionary.
thisWeek.DataByDay.Add(dayOfWeek, newObject);
```

---

I hope this answers your question (and future questions such as how to get the `WeekNo`), or at least is of some kind of help.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this. I meant as in tables in the database. Does your answer apply to them too?

Comment: I want to be able click on a week, and it shows all the days and then when I pick the day, it shows the readings taken on that day.